# How to increment local variables in elisp

Tags: elisp

I am trying to write a loop in elisp which prints the values sequencially.

I have tried the following code to print the sequence from 1.. which does not work. Please point the error in the code.

```
(let ((inc_variable 0))
  (message "%S" inc_variable)
  (while t (let ((inc_variable (+ inc_variable 1)))
    (message "%S" inc_variable))))
```

Comment: Note also that it is considered poor style to use underscores in symbol names in Elisp. Prefer `inc-variable` to `inc_variable`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are *two* bindings for `inc_variable` in this code. The outer binding has the value 0 and never changes. Then, each time round the loop, you create a new binding for `inc_variable` that gets set to one plus the value of the outer binding (which is always 0). So the inner binding gets the value 1 each time.

Remember that `let` always creates a *new* binding: if you want to update the value of an *existing* binding, use `setq`:

```
(let ((inc-variable 0))
  (while t 
    (message "%S" inc-variable)
    (setq inc-variable (+ inc-variable 1))))
```

Comment: the last line could be reduced to `(setq inc-variable (1+ inc-variable))))` using the build in function for incrementing `1+`

Comment: In that line I was copying the original poster for clarity. (Solve one problem at a time!) If it were my code I would have written `(incf inc-variable)`.

Comment: Nowadays you should use `cl-incf` from the `cl-lib` package rather than the deprecated `incf`.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to increment variable is to use `cl-incf` from `cl-lib`:

```lisp
(require 'cl-lib)
(let ((x 0))
  (cl-incf x)
  (message "%d" x)
)
```

The loop might look like this:

```lisp
(require 'cl-lib)
(let ((x 0))
  (while (< x 10) (cl-incf x)
         (insert (format "%d\n" x))
  )
)
```

Comment: Note that in modern Elisp code, `cl` is obsolete in favor of `cl-lib`, and `incf` has been replaced with `cl-incf`.

Comment: @RadonRosborough. I think `incf` not replaced.  It's still can be used without any error. It's aliased to `cl-incf` in `cl.el`

Comment: @azzamsa I know it still works. The point is it's deprecated. `cl.el` should never be used in new code. The reason for deprecation was to properly namespace the functions.